# Display addition of day to a localdate

Tags: thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf 3.

I display a localdate with

```
<div  th:text="${sampling.buildDate}" th:remove="tag"></div>
```

is it possible to add a number of day to this date?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to manipulate the date on the server and display it on the front-end.  This allows you to unit test and re-use the code, as well as keep the front-end logic easier for a UI designer to understand.

In your `@GetMapping` method:

`model.addAttribute("modifiedBuildDate", modifiedBuildDate);`

in the HTML:

`<div th:text=""${#temporals.format(modifiedBuildDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"" th:remove="tag">Some modified date</div>`

If you must manipulate it on the front-end (and I wouldn't recommend it), 
 you can try the utility `${#temporals.create(year,month,day)}` and modify the date as needed.